# Is it possible to create a blazor web assembly covering multiple subdomains, with nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I was wondering if the following setup is possible with blazor web assembly. I do have nginx running as a proxy and Cloudflare as DNS service so a combination of setups with these is also fine.

What I want to achieve:

1. The main program hosting on a domain called https://manage.mydomain.net
2. The main program is protected by a SSO (Azure AD B2C)
3. The main program has the option to enable and disable "features".
4. Each "feature" should be hosted on another subdomain (https://feature1.mydomain.net, https://feature2.mydomain.net)
5. Each "feature" should be callable directly by the configured subdomain of the "feature" (The SSO side should pop up and after a successful login you should be redirected to the main page of the "feature")

I know I can achieve that when implementing each "feature" as an app of their own. However, in the long run I want to publish the "features" as plugins that can be added to the main program and then activated if needed.

A small example or some pointers of how to achieve this so that I can build on that would be perfect.

Thanks